# How to convert python logging config to datadog grok parser rule?

Tags: logstash-grok, datadog

i have a logging config like

```
    logging.basicConfig(
        format='[%(asctime)s] {%(filename)s:%(lineno)d} %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
        level=logging.INFO,
        handlers=[
            logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
        ]
    )
```

It is really difficult for me to convert it to grok rules even i read the following

Parsing Examples: https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/processing/parsing/?tab=matcher#examples

Best Practices: https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/guide/log-parsing-best-practice/

Automatically generate a parsing rule from a Log Pattern: https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/explorer/analytics/patterns/#overview

Log Parsing FAQ: https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/faq/how-to-investigate-a-log-parsing-issue/

can any one help? thanks